# How do a case-insenstive Where clause in LINQ-to-NHibernate with the Oracle provider?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, oracle11g, linq-to-nhibernate

For example, given the following code, how is it possible to make the string comparison case-insensitive?

```
        var query = from employeeGroup in _session.Linq<EmployeeGroup>()
                    from employee in employeeGroup.Employee
                    where employee.UserName == username
                    select employeeGroup.EmployeeGroupName;
```

The NHibernate.Linq.SqlClient.SqlClientExtensions.Upper() method might help but this only seems to be available with SQL Server.

If I use the System.String class to do the comparison, I get an error: "Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection.".  I believe this is because there is no direct mapping that NHibernate can do to SQL.

Comment: In the current version this should now be supported. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/linq-to-nhibernate-progress-report-a-christmas-gift.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, NHibernate Linq [does not support](http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg10112.html) case insensitive matching. This isn't a problem for SQL Server which is case insensitive but obviously is for Oracle. I think you'll have to use the Criteria API or HQL for this.

Comment: I disagree.  Please see "IsInsensitiveLike" option below.

Answer (score 1):

When using nHibernate QueryOver, you can use IsInsensitiveLike with MatchMode.Exact.  This makes it a case-insensitive match, and the "Exact" means it will match "John" exactly vs. finding "Johnson" etc.

```
var foo = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Where(x => x.Firstname.IsInsensitiveLike("John", MatchMode.Exact)).List();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is a Criteria API example:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))
    .Add(new Expression.EqExpression("Firstname", "John", true))
    .List<Customer>();
```

The Boolean parameter at the end of the EqExpression method determines case-insensitivity.

Comment: It seems this was deprecated in NHibernate 2 - this expression was replaced with InsensitiveLike.